# Does applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOption gets called when an iOS app is updated?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Does `applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOption` gets called when an iOS app is updated. I am updating the structure of my coredata model and want to wipe out all the data during the upgrade and have written the logic for it in `didFinishLaunchingApplication` method.

Comment: Launching an application and installing it on the device are two separate things. As currently standing, your question doesn't make sense. Please narrow it down to *either* case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but only in the sense that it gets called upon every app launch, including the first launch after an app upgrade. (The older method you may be referring to, `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, is deprecated in iOS 3.0 and later; the one with options is the primary one for all circumstances)

If you want to actually detect an upgrade condition, you'll need to leave "breadcrumb" data for yourself somewhere (e.g. in user defaults) indicating either the last version launched (and check if it's different), or for something complicated like a data migration, you can store a flag indicating "data exists currently in the new format", which you set on new installs (if there's no data) or on upgrades after doing the migration.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! i have left a breadcrumb in the defaults as you have mentioned, but this logic is there in -applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, so just wanted to confirm whether this will work out and this is a very crucial update.

Comment: @raf: You can test this yourself. Roll back your source tree to the commit that you shipped for your last update, put that on the device,and then update to latest, rebuild, and redeploy. This should correctly simulate the update.

Answer (score 0):

It gets called every time it launches (not when reopening from the background). Updates don't have to do anything with this